# Equivalent topologies on Real projective space $RP^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

This is homework,so no answers please.

Prove that the topology on $RP^{n}$  given by the standard smooth structure  (lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}/\{0\}$ and $\tau_{1}$) is equal to the quotient topology induced by ∼ from the standard topology on $S^{n}$ ($\tau_{2}$) (identifying antipodal points).

The standard smooth structure is:
The chart from $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $\phi_{i}[x_{1},...,x_{n}]=(\frac{x_{1}}{x_{i}},...,\hat{1},...,\frac{x_{n}}{x_{i}})$ and $U_{i}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}/\{0\}:x_{i}\neq 0\}$. The induced topology $\tau_{1}$ is: U is open if $\phi_{i}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The $\phi_{i}(U)$ is the intersection of open cone [U] with affine hyperplane with $x^{i}=1$

I am Not comparing $\tau_{2}$ to the quotient topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}/\{0\}/\sim$, where $x\sim y$ iff $x=\lambda y$.

any mistakes in showing $\tau_{1}=\tau_{2}$:

Given open U in $\mathbb{S}^{n}/\sim$, we have $\pi_{2}^{-1}(U)=U\cup (-U)$ is open in $\mathbb{S}^{n}$. Then via chart $\phi_{a}$ of $\mathbb{S}^{n}$, we get open $V=\phi_{a}(U)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then by appropriate shrinking we get $\tilde{V}=\phi_{i}(U)$ open and so $U \in \tau_{1}$.

Conversely, given $U \in \tau_{1}$, we can reverse the above process to get $U\cup (-U)$ being open (since -U is open). Thus, $U\in \tau_{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are working rather hard. Here is a hint: if $f : X \to Q$ is a quotient map and $Q$ is Hausdorff, and if $Y \subset X$ is a compact subset such that $f \mid Y : Y \to Q$ is surjective, then $f \mid Y$ is also a quotient map. Therefore $Q$ can be viewed as a quotient of both $X$ and $Y$. By carefully choosing $X$ and $Y$ and $f$, you should be able to answer your question quite easily.

ADDED: Here's a few more details of the hint. The "topology on $RP^n$ given by the standard smooth structure" is indeed a quotient topology. It is not a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, but instead it is a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$. Those charts in that atlas you describe are quotient maps from saturated (open) subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ to their (open) images in $RP^n$, and they are also restrictions of the globally defined quotient map $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\} \to RP^n$.

Comment: I suppose $X=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$,which is not compact

Comment: @TKM: I overlooked the noncompactness of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0\}$, and have rewritten my hint.

Comment: actually, there is only one quotient topology (that of $\mathbb{S}^{n}$). The other topology is induced by the atlas I wrote above. You are referring to a different problem: equivalence of two quotient topologies,one from $\mathbb{S}^{n}$ and the other from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: @TKM: I added some details to my hint. Does that help?